# Titration color change duration

Tags: titration

Why is it that in titration a color change occurs initially but then the solution quickly reverts to its previous color?

Thanks so much!

Comment: You need to be specific in your question. What are you titrating and what colors are seen?

Answer (score 1):

As an example, let's say you're titrating a strong acid with a strong base using phenolphthalein as an indicator. As you initially add the base to the acid, you may not see the color change occurring because the acid so readily neutralizes the added base. This is because of the large concentration of H+. As you approach a basic pH, however, concentration of H+ decreases and the acid is not able to neutralize the base as quickly. As the base disperses in the solution more slowly, the phenolphthalein will have time to react and show a slight color change.